# AWS ACM certificate state is pending validation and not changing to issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-acm

I have requested a public ACM certificate and I have selected the DNS validation method. After requesting the certificate it went to Pending validation state. I have created a hosted zone in Route 53 with the same domain name which I have used for my certificate. After creating the certificate I got the option "Create record in Route 53". I have created the record in Route 53 with the CNAME and it displayed as " Success
The DNS record was written to your Route 53 hosted zone. It can take 30 minutes or longer for the changes to propagate and for AWS to validate the domain and issue the certificate.". But the status of the certificate is not getting changed and it is still in pending validation only. After some time the "Create record in Route 43" option is getting enabled again. I have tried the same process multiple times almost one day but the status is not getting changed. Can someone please help to fix the issue.

Answer (score 30):

In the AWS Console (Web UI), on the Certificate Manager page,

- Expand the certificate that is pending
- Expand the table that has domain and validation status
- Click the blue button that says "Create record in Route 53" (you can also do this manually)
  [image]
- Give it about 10 minutes

Or follow these instructions from AWS - [Why is my AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) certificate DNS validation status still pending validation?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-pending-validation/)

Comment: The only valid and true answer. All of the rest is crap.

Answer (score 9):

Having the same issue here and I found out that my problem is in the NS record in my domain. My mistake was I didn't update the Name Servers in my domain, what I did was the opposite. I updated the values of the NS record in R53 based on the NS on my domain then I realized that the right thing to do was to update your NS (Name Servers) of your domain to the values of the NS record in R53. Haha (english is not my native language btw).

Just make sure you have the correct Name Servers and correct CNAME suggested by ACM. I waited a day before and still Pending Validation, but when I fixed it it took only a few minutes for my certificate to be issued.

Comment: How long did it take? Mine says up to 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the Name Servers(NS) in your domain with the Name Servers (NS) of your NS record.

Dashboard > Domain Registration > Domain > Domain Name > Action > Edit name server

Comment: This was my issue exactly. Thanks.

Comment: This was it for me

Comment: Thanks for this! The reason why I needed to update my NS (which I would've never known if I didn't see this post) is because I transferred my domain from GoDaddy to AWS Route 53. I was waiting for my ACM to validate for over 30 hours before I thought something was up as I had done this previously via godaddy and it was < 10 mins

Answer (score 4):

What I would do is:

- Verify that the DNS returns what is expected.

For that you can use `dig` (Linux) or `nslookup` (Windows), or even better > https://www.digwebinterface.com

If you don't get what is expected, you need to reconfigure the DNS.

- Once it is verified, wait a little bit (10 min to 2h I'd say).

Something to read while you wait:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-regions.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html
- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-pending-validation/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/domain-ownership-validation.html

Comment: 10m to 2h!  Frustrating that it can take so long.  Especially since you cannot know if something is wrong or not.  my nslookup works fine, but it's been 30+ minutes so far

Comment: It's terrible. In my career, I've probably done domain validation 50 times. I don't ever remember it being anything other than instant.  The lack of a "Check again" button is maddening.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to check if you verified the email you used in registering the domain. If the domain is suspended the Certificate would not be issued. You can request another verification link.

Answer (score 1):

If your NS is Godaddy, check if there's a dot added at the end of the DNS record.
<random_value>.acm-validations.aws." is rejected while "<random_value>.acm-validations.aws" is accepted.

[Default trailing period added by DNS provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html)

Comment: Definitely confusing.  On GoDaddy the value ***does end in*** a dot as shown on the godaddy DNS page.  And it DOES work.  As you say, sometimes if "you add a dot" on entry, it wopn't work, but other times it seems to.  Perhaps GoDaddy changed it really recently, IDK

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to AWS Certificate Manager (ACM)

[image]

2. Click in the certificate that is pending

[image]

3. Click the "Create record in Route 53" and
4. In Route53 you'll see the CNAME records there

[image]

That's it. Then after 7 minutes, in my case, you'll then see the success

[image]